# Summarize specific data only within report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

How can I get the sum of specific records from the "credit" column in my Crystal report? I only want to summarize records where the "status" column is equal to "PR". I could do this in SQL, but I'd want to show this information within the report itself.

Comment: I would suggest adding more content to this question, to help us get to the answer that you need to resolve this problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Running Total for this. RTs are like summaries but you can set the conditions for which records are summarized or not. Make a RT that evaluates a sum of *Credit*, never resets, and Uses a Formula. Then enter the formula where *Status* is equal to "PR".

Keep in mind RTs can only be placed below the records they are summarizing. If you want to put the total *before* the data, you'll have to go back and use SQL again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can follow simple steps to achive this..

1st create a formula like

```
@PR_Amount = if {Status} = 'PR' then {CR_Amount} else 0;
```

place it into detail section

2nd create another formula like

```
@PR_Status_SUM = Sum ({@PR_AMOUNT})
```

place it into report footer..

Hope this will help..